# Understanding passport.authenticate('local') syntax bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, passport.js

**tl;dr:** I want to make sense of the `(req, res)` bit at the end of the code.

I'm having a hard time understanding a piece of code involving `passport.authenticate()' using the local strategy.

I have the following (working) route:

```
router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, function (err, user, info)  {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: "Something went wrong",
        user: user
      })
    }

      return res.send({user, info})
  }) (req, res) // What´s this??
})
```

As far as I can tell, the route calls `passport.authenticate()`, which then calls the Local Strategy I've set in a different file, which in turn returns err, user, info. After the callback is executed, this code handles possible errors and, if all went ok, it sends back the user along the messages set up in the Local Strategy...

What I don't understand is the last bit. What is `(req, res)` exactly doing there? I know it's a critical bit because the route won't work without that line, but I don't understand why, nor what exactly it is (is it calling a function with parameters req and res? is it returning req and res?), since I don't recognize the pattern (it does resemble an IIFE, but then again I wouldn't know what exactly is it calling, since `passport.authenticate()` is itself a function call... or is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It passing the parameters to function that will be returned.

please check the source code for more information and see whats going on.

[passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js)

@Dijkie85, forgive me, I have been busy.

conider:

```
function getFoo(arg1, arg2) {
  return function getFoo(arg3, arg4) {
    return (arg3 + arg4) || "foo";
  }
}
console.log(getFoo()); // "Function: getFoo"
console.log(getFoo()()); // "foo"
console.log(getFoo()(1, 2)); // 3
```

in authenticate.js file you are in the same situation, too. you can remove logics for simplicity and check again:

```
module.exports = function authenticate(passport, name, options, callback) {
  return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**req**, **res** and **next** are provided by express to return fucntion.

Comment: What specifically passes parameters?

Comment: Sorry I tried to look at the code by I'm still confused. Could you provide a more elaborate answer? Thank you

Comment: @Dijkie85 It is JavaScript closure. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, see the example code below:

```
//outerFunction returns a function (namely innerFunction) instead of just a value/object
function outerFunction() {
  var x = 5;
  function innerFunction(x) {
    return x * 2;
  }
  return innerFunction;
}

//calling only outerFunction by using outerFunction()
var result1 = outerFunction();
console.log('Result on invoking only outer function: \n'+result1); 
//returns innerFunction() method NOT any value/object

//invoking innerFunction() by using outerFunction()(10) and passing 10 as argument to innerFunction
var result2 = outerFunction()(10);
console.log('Result is '+result2); 
//returns 20

//invoking innerFunction() by using outerFunction()() and not passing any argument to innerFunction
var result3 = outerFunction()();
console.log('Result is '+result3); 
//returns NaN because no value was passed to the innerFunction's parameter x`
```

Comparing this code to your code:
passport.authenticate('local',anonyFunction)(req, res);

So, passport has an outer function called authenticate and it returns an inner function which takes 2 arguments: req and res.

Taking a look at the source code of passport.authenticate in https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js

Line Number 94:  return function authenticate(req, res, next)

So, your mystery (req, res) is passed to the above line of code.

Did that clear your question?